# Might someone explain why this is marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

[This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201035/posterior-distribution-of-normal-with-gamma-prior) has been marked a duplicate of [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2635/conjugate-prior-for-a-gamma-distribution). The former concerns the posterior of a normal likelihood with known mean and gamma precision; the latter, the conjugate prior of a gamma distribution.

In what way are these duplicates? What am I missing?

Comment: I voted to reopen.

Comment: @amoeba Myself as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The thread is now reopened.**

As nobody explained here why this should be a duplicate and as I could not see it myself, I voted to reopen. Unfortunately, this suggestion only got three upvotes and died out (even though I edited this thread at certain moment to push this Q again to the top of the Meta).

So I raised a flag for moderator attention and  explained the situation (in the flag comment space) as best as  I could, linking to this Meta thread. As a result, one of the moderators reopened the thread.

I believe this illustrates well

1. that it tends to be much easier to close a question than to reopen it and that in general it tends to be difficult to revert previous decisions;
2. how such situations could be handled.